# How to import a svg file in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, webpack, import

I have a custom React + Typescript + Webpack project. I need to import a simple .svg file and use it in a component. Typescript claims it:

> Cannot find module

I've installed svgr, added it to my webpack config, created a custom.d.ts file allowing svg import in typescript and specified it in the tsconfig.json. Nothing works (I run the component in Storybook for the moment).

Here is my webpack:

```js
 module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: { loader: "babel-loader" },
        },
        { test: /\.css$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"] },
        { test: /\.svg$/, use: ["@svgr/webpack"] },
        { test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/, use: ["file-loader"] },
      ],
    },
```

My component

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Account from "./account.svg";

export default function Icon({ icon }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Account/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The custom.d.ts

```js
declare module "*.svg" {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}

// added to tsconfig.json
"include": ["./src/**/*", "./custom.d.ts"],
```

The svg is a simple `<svg><path blabla/></svg>` file.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and I found the solution [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/react-best-way-of-importing-svg-the-how-and-why-f7c968272dd9).

I personnaly used this method :

1. I imported my logo as a ReactComponent.
2. Then I used it in my code :)

```js
import React from "react";
import { ReactComponent as MySvgFile } from "path/to/file.svg";

export default function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MySvgFile />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where does the <Logo /> come from? What do you do with mySvgFile?

Comment: Oops, sorry, it was my real component name ! I'll correct for <mySvgFile /> !